# Single source shortest paths with even path

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

Given directed graph with non negative weights and vertex s.
I need an algorithm that finds shortest paths from s to all vertices and the paths have to be even.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Single-source shortest paths with even weight](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109481/single-source-shortest-paths-with-even-weight)

Comment: There is a search bar on the top of every page. Have you tried searching for ["single source shortest path even"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=single+source+shortest+paths+even)?